# >50mb file upload on Lucee (deployed on Tomcat) through API/Rest request failled without error

Tags: apache, rest, tomcat, coldfusion, lucee

I'm currently working on file uploading in **Lucee** (deployed on **Tomcat**).

I'm sending an html form to an **API**, that keep the file temp. and then send it to our **backend** through **http post request** (formfield with payload + file) to **invoke a cfc with a proper method**.

That request goes to **onRequestStart** then **onCFCRequest** that invoke our CFC with our params. A response is returned to our API.

Problem is with file **<50 mb it works perfectly** but with larger files, the response we are receiving is **a dump of the invoked component** (without going through onCFCRequest), our file is in our temp folder, the **form struct is not empty** but our **HTTPRequest content is empty**.

Already tried to add params to Tomcat and Lucee like

**`maxHttpHeaderSize`** and **`maxPostSize`** in server.xml

**`<max-file-size>`** and **`<max-request-size>`**

I'm not getting any errors from Tomcat and Lucee about size limits.

Do you have any idea of what is happening ?

**EDIT:**

I have found this issue:
http://www.rupeshk.org/blog/index.php/2007/08/coldfusion-8-changes-with-file-upload/

Do you know how can i keep the content on my http request? 
Because it's empty (no payload, no file) so it doesn't trigger the onCFCRequest handler. Thanks

Comment: Check your exception log.  Dollars to donuts it's a java heap space error.

Comment: Hey, already checked all logs, no errors reported.

Already set 2048m for Java, no heap space error.